# What overarching term would include use of a Fourier transform, other similar integral transforms, and their discrete counterparts?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, linear-transformations, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

**Question:** What overarching terms could be used to refer to the use of a Fourier transform, Hankel transform, etc. as well as discrete versions of those, such as a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT), etc.?

**Context:**
This is for language describing a step within a patent claim. This step in principle involves the use of any transform that could be used to represent a 2D image in terms of a different set of basis images (such as an FFT, where the basis set are 2D sinusoidal waves).

Because it's for a patent claim, it's not necessarily math jargon specifically I'm looking for (which might be a bad choice if it's not commonly understood in the community, or has a different common meaning), but something which could reasonably be interpreted in the science/signal engineering, etc. communities to refer to what I want it to.

**My ideas:**
My initial thought was to say something like 'integral transform', but maybe that wouldn't really apply to the discrete versions - particularly something like the FFT since you could argue that no integration is really involved.

Another thought was something like 'mathematical transform', but I'm afraid that's too broad, because it could apply to simply squaring functions, etc.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out legal or law forum rather than a technical one. "any transform that can be used for..." sounds very broad for being acceptable for such a claim, but I am just an engineer and no lawyer.

Comment: There are plenty of other elements of the patent that are very specific -this particular element needs to be very broad. We have a patent attorney for all the legal stuff. I just couldn't think of a broad way to describe this particular part for him. The patent attorney typically writes the bulk of a patent, but is also typically not an expert in your field - so it can be helpful for the inventor to help him get the right language, etc. right.

Comment: If you have an attorney he probably knows much more of the legal stuff than we do.

Comment: Also it is incredibly untactical to ask openly on the internet about this. Someone may figure out what you plan to apply for and apply before you.

Comment: I think the answer is "Operator Methods"

Comment: @dbx Or more commonly, "Operator Theory."

Comment: @mathreadler Yeah, don't worry. We know what we're doing where the patent is concerned.

Comment: I suppose something related to 'operator theory' could be used, but would that be commonly understood by engineers in DSP, image analysis, etc.? I'm a physcist, so I'm not sure how much engineers are familiar with operators.